# How to run jar with multiple main methods with spark-submit?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to take multiple Scala main method in a single jar and run my spark application.

Can I specify what class should run? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

When you use spark-submit to run your jar on Spark cluster you specify the class with `main` method with `class` parameter.

**Example:**

You have a jar with two main methods. one in class `com.example.Ex1` and `com.example.Ex2`. To run first main method you should submit your app with class parameter equal to the full class name of the first application

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.example.Ex1 \
  --master local[8] \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
```